# Showing that $\sum_j e^{-jx}x^j$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm not sure how to go about applying the Weierstrass M-test to this series. Clearly each term is less than 1, but could I actually say that $|xe^{-x}| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$, so this series is bounded above by summing $\sum_{j} {\frac{1}{2^j}}$?

For $x > 0$.

Comment: You can do that or $|xe^{-x}|\leq e^{-1}$.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Mhenni! Any idea as to how I would actually compute the sum?

Comment: Untrue at $x=-1$.

Comment: What is the domain of definition here? As @Did points out, this is not true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For summing the series, you can use the geometric series

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k=\frac{1}{1-t}.$$

In your case

> $$ t = xe^{-x} .$$